# examples of the lower semicontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

The following is the definition of [lower semicontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity):

> Let $T$ be a topological space and $f:T\to\Bbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ a function. $f$ is said to be lower semicontinuous if the set $\{x\in T:f(x)>a\}$ is open in $T$ for every $a\in\Bbb{R}$.

The Wikipedia article gives several examples. But I don't see why one would need the extanded value and how it would be useful. Could anyone come up with an example of lower semicontinuous function with the extended value $+\infty$ being assumed at some point in the domain? Why is the extended value useful in this definition?

Answer (score 1):

Lower semicontinuity is also the "right minimum regularity" for superharmonic functions, a good example would be (in the complex plane)
$$
u(z) = \log \frac{1}{|z|}.
$$
where the value at $0$ is taken as $+\infty$. Now, this example is still continuous (as an extended real-valued function), but if we put
$$
u(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_j \log\frac{1}{|z-\frac1j|}
$$
where $\alpha_j$ is small enough to make $u(0) < \infty$, we get something a little more interesting: a lower semi-continuous function where $u(1/j) = +\infty$ for all positive integers $j$, but $u(0) < +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be continuous and $K \subset T$ a closed subset, then

$$ f_K(x)= \begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if } x\in K \\
+\infty & \text{if } x\notin K
\end{cases}$$

is a lower semicontinuous function as

$$\{ f_K >a\} = T\setminus K \cup \{ f>a\}.$$